# Entity Framework on model create pass arguments in constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

When Entity Framework retrieves data from database and creates a new model class for that, how to pass values to the constructor instead of assigning them to the properties?

For example :

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Customer(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
    }
}
```

So when I call to `_context.Customers.ToList();` I want to pass values to the constructor, instead of assigning them to the properties.

Comment: Please always tag the applicable EF version. The differences between versions can be significant, esp. core vs. "classic". EF-core now supports [entity types with constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors). By the way, I don't see what calling `ToList()` has to do with constructors.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, Entity Framework constructs entities using parameterless constructors and sets the properties value using setters. Although, neither parameterless constructor nor setters have to be public.